# How to enable python process to access all the memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, virtual-memory

I have 62 GB RAM in a Blade server and a Python code that needs to process 20 GB file. I want to process the complete file in the memory and tried to load the file in memory. However, it is crashing and throwing `MemoryError`.

I am not sure why it would be like this?

*I know I can load the file incrementally and this error can be mitigated.*

But my question is more fundamental, why python cannot load this file into memory even if so much memory is available.

When I type `ulimit`, it is  showing `unlimited`. So I would think all the memory available to the OS should be available to the pyrhon process.

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256797
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Then why my process cannot access memory.

Before running the code:

`free -mg`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             62           1          52           0           8          61
Swap:            31           0          31
```

```
def read_from_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as reader:
        text = reader.read()
        return text
```

Comment: Python might be using more memory to represent the file than the file's size. Have you actually checked the memory usage of the process as it's running to see if it's hitting your limit? And are you sure you're using a 64-bit version of Python?

Comment: How are you loading the file?

Comment: added the code.

Comment: Python objects are larger than the bytes they represent. If you file consisted of nothing but `ö` and a newline, then the `str` object returned by `read` would use 75 bytes, not 3.

Comment: @chepner I have added the output and we have plenty of free memory.

Comment: Under the hood python uses c `malloc()` and doesn't limit memory allocation. You posted `free` result before running code, could you post also after running code?

Comment: Also can you do something like this `bytearray(1024 * 1024 * 1000 * 60)`?

Comment: @chepner yeah but that would be a constant overhead. Lots of small strings are inefficient memory-wise in Python. One large string shouldn't be, I think.

Comment: What does `python - c "import sys; print(sys.maxsize)"` give you?

Comment: >>> import sys; print(sys.maxsize)
9223372036854775807